# формат хранения данных

Tags: python, json

Возникла необходимость сохранять данные формата: словарь из пары в список пар. Пишу на Python3.

Хотел использовать json, но к сожалению он не понимает tuple и выдает ошибку

`TypeError: keys must be a string`.

Подскажите, в каком формате можно сохранять данные такого типа в файл?

Comment: Например в Pickle... Вам с какой целью надо сохранять? Должен ли файл быть `"human readable"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать YAML (если нужен файл, который можно открыть в редакторе и увидеть значения):

```
In [132]: import yaml

In [133]: d = {(0.5, 0.5): list('1011'), (2, 2): list('0000'), (1, 1): list('1001')}

In [134]: d
Out[134]:
{(0.5, 0.5): ['1', '0', '1', '1'],
 (1, 1): ['1', '0', '0', '1'],
 (2, 2): ['0', '0', '0', '0']}

In [135]: with open('c:/temp/out.yml', 'w') as f:
     ...:     yaml.dump(d, f, indent=4)
     ...:
```

Результат:

```
? !!python/tuple [0.5, 0.5]
: ['1', '0', '1', '1']
? !!python/tuple [1, 1]
: ['1', '0', '0', '1']
? !!python/tuple [2, 2]
: ['0', '0', '0', '0']
```

Чтение из YAML:

```
In [136]: with open('c:/temp/out.yml') as f:
     ...:     new = yaml.load(f)
     ...:

In [137]: new
Out[137]:
{(0.5, 0.5): ['1', '0', '1', '1'],
 (1, 1): ['1', '0', '0', '1'],
 (2, 2): ['0', '0', '0', '0']}
```

---

или Pickle (файл будет бинарным - посмотреть значения в редакторе будет сложно ;):

```
In [146]: import pickle

In [147]: with open('c:/temp/out.pickle', 'wb') as f:
     ...:     pickle.dump(d, f)
     ...:

In [148]: with open('c:/temp/out.pickle', 'rb') as f:
     ...:     d2 = pickle.load(f)
     ...:

In [149]: d2
Out[149]:
{(0.5, 0.5): ['1', '0', '1', '1'],
 (1, 1): ['1', '0', '0', '1'],
 (2, 2): ['0', '0', '0', '0']}
```